# how can Excel VBA function AUTO CALCULATE itself after I change the function code?

Tags: vba, excel

I have wrote a  Excel VBA function and used it in many cells. However I find the function is wrong now. Then I alter the function code, but the cells' value does not change automaticly unless I click the cell again. It's so boring and meaningless.

How can Excel VBA function AUTO CALCULATE itself after I change the function ?
`

Comment: press F9 if I remember well

Comment: Wait - are you looking for a VB code that will re-enable auto calculation, or just asking how to recalculate a cell?  Also, please post the code you do have as it will help us understand where you're coming from.

Comment: I just ask how to recalculate a cell, thank you.@BruceWayne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press Control+Shift+F9 after modifying the function.

Comment: I Press Control+Shift+F9 after modifying the function, but the cell's value does not change.

Comment: What about control+alt+shift F9 ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

`Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`

Comment: That won't help Excel realise the UDF has been edited. Especially since for that line to do anything the UDF must be called.AFAIK editing a UDF does not trigger a recalc, nor does it "dirty" the cells containing it.